# VS 2010 Javascript Intellisense not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am writing javascript code which uses jQuery and unfortunately when I create a .js file with the following:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.2.js" />
(function($) {

  // use $ here

})(jQuery);
```

I don't get any intellisense for $.  However I still get intellisense if I use "jQuery".  This seems like an oversight to me because Visual Studio should recognise that I am creating an anonymous function and immediately executing it with jQuery passed in.

Does anyone have a workaround / fix?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no work-around I'm aware of, except doing this:

```
(function($) {
  $ = jQuery; //remove or comment this before it goes to the minifier
  // use $ here

})(jQuery);
```

I do this when strip that out `$ = jQuery;` as part of the build (if I need intellisense that badly in the file).  I'm hoping the Visual Studio team fixes this in SP1, but I also haven't seen any news saying they have yet.  [Check out Michaud's blog here with a few quotes from the VS team on the issue](http://www.bnomad.com/2010/07/getting-visual-studio-jquery.html).

Comment: How do you strip this out during your build?

Comment: @Tahir - it totally depends on your build process, currently I'm using Chirpy to minify my files (as they're saved): http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ As part of that engine I'm removing them...I hope post my enhancements to Chirpy to their project in the next week, soon as I have a chunk of time to do so

Comment: Just curious: does it actually need to be stripped out?  (I know it makes the parameter pointless to keep it in as you could easily do "var $ = jQuery" in the closure instead.)

Comment: @Tahir - if you did `var` you'd be alright, otherwise you might overwrite `$`, for example if Prototype was on the page.